# What are the priorities which returning exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Consider this custom code simply designed to ask my question

This method is simply one of many methods in a class called CompleteGraph. Details are not required.
GetEdges makes 2 checks - one to verify if complete-graph has been constructed, if yes it checks if input is null or not.

But I could also swap the checks and check that `nodeId==null` before, which means in even both the conditions that throw exceptions hold true, the order of exception received by users differ.

My question is - are there some guidelines / links on order of returning exceptions for a better user experience ?

```
public Map<T, Double> getEdges(T nodeId) {
        if (isGraphComplete()) throw new IllegalStateException("The graph is not complete graph.");
        if (nodeId == null) throw new NullPointerException("The nodeId input is null");
        Map<T, Double> map = heuristic.get(nodeId);
        return map == null ? map :  Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
    }
```

Comment: Give them the most critical error first.

Comment: No point swapping the checks if you know that graph has to be complete  before nodeId can be used. I mean, it finally boils down to what @SotiriosDelimanolis has pointed out above.

Comment: following link gives good guide lines, not specifically throwing order but handling exceptions in general https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, I don't think there are general guidelines on which order to throw validation exceptions (or any exceptions for that matter). I also don't agree with the other answer to this question by Elliott that you shouldn't throw unchecked exceptions.

Since your question is slightly subjective, here is my more subjective answer. I think it comes down to what you think provides a better "user experience" for the caller. If you were to call the method, what would you expect to happen. Then as long as it is documented to the caller, it shouldn't matter.

If you don't know who your caller is (i.e. your class is in a library) and don't know their use-case, it's hard to know how a caller will handle the exceptions. You can't make an informed decision on which you think they would like to handle first.

Now specifically about your code, I usually go by the "if you know you're going to fail, fail quickly" philosophy. If your isGraphComplete method is more expensive, and you know your method might fail later because the argument is null, I would do the cheap null check first.

Answer (score 2):

Users do not use developer APIs. Developers do, design for them! That is, generally I would not throw unchecked Exceptions (but I would focus on documenting all of the Exceptions I did throw, I might even define my own checked Exception - then there is less to document)!

Comment: Your point is valid, but I guess he was probably referring to developer as the (API's) user :)